# How can I find nearest cinema?

Tags: geolocation

I m developing a location aware application for my final year  project
I need to find a way to locate nearest cineWorld cinema.. basically the app aquires the user location and then looks up a database for matching cinema id.... but it fails if there is no cinema in user's city location therefore I need to find nearest cinema

Comment: use gps coordinates for both - and compute the distance from current location to each cinema - then optimize

Comment: if you know the city name, you could use Google search - http://www.google.com/search?q=movies+in+chennai&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&safe=active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google's places API solved my problem